# Jenkins Linux Master + Windows Build agent?

Tags: linux, windows, java, jenkins, continuous-integration

Will a Jenkins Linux master work with a Windows build agent? Does anyone know if this set up can be achieved and is supported? Just looking for a proof of concept and that this can work so I can proceed with getting this set up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very common configuration and well documented on the Jenkins site. Just install the [WMI Windows Agents (aka windows-slaves)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-slaves/). We've been running this from Jenkins 1.408.1 / 2013 to latest (2.289.2), w / VM servers from W2K8 to W2K16.

We used to launch via JNLP but switched to launch via DCOM and had [no issues](https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slaves-plugin/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.adoc) as it's easier manage (same as [ssh / linux agents](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-slaves/)).

There are now also [Docker images](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/05/11/docker-windows-agents/) available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where is this set up documented on Jenkins site? I am searching but can't seem to find it.

Comment: And how do you launch via DCOM? I'm sorry, but you throw out a lot of technologies but don't provide any guides or documentation. Could you at least point me in the right direction?